# EXTJS 4.1 how I select the next leaf node in a tree panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, extjs4.1

I try to select the next leaf node of that currently selected.

For example:

- group1

  - leaf1
  - leaf2
  - leaf3
- group2

  - leaf4

The leaf2 is currently selected. When I click on a button how to unselect this node and select the next node (in this example the next node is leaf3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting a reference to the node that is to be removed, use the `nextSibling` property to get a reference to the next node, and select it.

Something like this:

```
var node = treePanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];

var nextNode = node.nextSibling;

if (nextNode) treePanel.getSelectionModel().select(nextNode);
```

Working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d1n)